# Reverse-engineering results in a published research paper

Tags: publications

I am trying to implement work in someone else's published IEEE research paper, to verify its results and observe some data. To fully implement what was done, I will need to implement the published algorithm - this will involve some reverse-engineering of what was done in the paper.

Normally, when I face particular programming problems, I might use Stack Overflow or other sites to ask specific questions. Given that doing so it this case would reveal that I was reverse-engineering published work, are there any specific professional or ethical issues around the reverse-engineering aspect of this?

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "implementing?" Are you writing one? And for point 3, can you also explain a bit more clearly? Do you mean can you cite a paper that is still not finished?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight: I just mean implementing an already published research paper just to verify its results and observe some data.

Comment: Have you asked the authors of the original paper whether they'd be willing to make their implementation (source code) available for you to work with?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: I have not asked them for their implementation. I am not kind of sure whether it is perfectly allowed to ask them for their implementation.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to ask.  They may or may not be willing to share.

Answer (score 3):

Reimplementing published methods is a perfectly valid and common thing to do. Research papers should describe the utilized methods to enable other people to reperform the experiments and verify the results, so I don't see a reason not to speak publicly about what you're doing.

Comment: In fact, this used to be the standard which helped keep science accurate, and it's all too lacking today. "Checking other people's work" is vitally important but doesn't draw funding or reputation.